# Let Django model save() to firebase but not to database

Tags: python, django, firebase

I have the following model in my models.py, I want to use it to save chat messages to firebase so it doesn't hit my own database. I use in handlers the post_save signal.

```
class FirebaseMessage(models.Model):
    chatbox = models.ForeignKey(ChatBox, related_name='msgs', db_index=True)
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, db_index=True)
    message = models.CharField(max_length=1000)

    @property
    def firebase_key(self):
        m_identifier = str(self.id)
        return 'sub_messages/%s/' % (m_identifier)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
```

My handlers.py:

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=FirebaseMessage, dispatch_uid='s.chatmessage_handler')
def chatmessage_handler(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    serializer = ChatMessageSerializer(instance)
    message_endpoint = ''.join(instance.firebase_key)
    client.patch(message_endpoint, serializer.data)
```

I already tried overriding the save() method in FirebaseMessage but it's not saving to both then, probably because the post_save isn't signaled. What's the best way to save the object to firebase but not to my own database?

Comment: Do you want to save to both databases or not? Your wording is conflicting.

Comment: @Selcuk I want it (the messages) to save to Firebase only, so no chat message is saved in my own database and my own database isn't hit constantly with messages.

Comment: I would override `save()` method of model. Can you post what did you try?

Comment: @Selcuk I didn't try much because I didn't know what I was doing exactly, I just tried to return it directly so it wouldn't save but then the post_save wasn't signaled too.

Comment: ChatMessageSerializer is a DRF serializer?

Comment: @Satyajeet Yep it is

Comment: So most Probably you are using Viewset also..?

Comment: @Satyajeet for that view i'm using class CreateChatMessageView(CreateAPIView)

Comment: have you tried the given answer....?

Comment: @Satyajeet trying it right now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you need to listen for any events here, because you want to completely exclude the database saving functionality. So just move your `chatmessage_handler` functionality into your `model.save()` method.

Something like this should do the trick.

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    serializer = ChatMessageSerializer(self)
    message_endpoint = ''.join(self.firebase_key)
    client.patch(message_endpoint, serializer.data)
```